# Have mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification: complete before listening NSFetchResultsControllers pounce and update themselves

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios5, merge, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an `NSFetchedResultsController` (FRC) backing a Table View. By definition, it's listening in for changes in it's managed object context (MOC) relevant to its defining fetch request.

While this table view is visible, I may have a small import (like ~ dozen records) I run, with managed objects that will be relevant to the watching FRC.

I run the import on a peer MOC to the one backing the table view. Both MOC's are `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`, with a common parent MOC of `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`.

As soon as the import completes with a save, my previously setup notification fires a handler, that simply does a `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:`

```
- (void)scratchpadContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)saveNotification {
    log4Info(@"Default Context now merging changes from Scratchpad Context save notification.");
    [self.defaultContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:saveNotification];
}
```

**Question:**
How do I get the `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` to complete before any listening FRCs get notified?

**Motivation**
The FRC's new data coming in acts as a trigger of sorts in my application, which is fine, as long as *all* of the merged changes are available. My FRC acts immediately, not having complete information.

I'm going to remove logic needing the FRC to be patient this way, but it got me concerned that I'm not aware of a way to "lock" change notifications from going out until the entire merge operation is complete.

Answer (score 0):

idStar,

A way to force a synchronous to all `-save:`s is to have them serialize their merges through a private serial queue where the last item actually performs the merge to the main MOC. Just because an item is saved to the persistent store, doesn't mean it has to be merged right away. You will have to merge the `userInfo` dictionaries yourself before submitting the dictionaries to the main MOC.

Andrew

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that instead of using mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification: when the save notification fires, I look at all the managed objects in the userInfo dictionary individually? This much I follow, but how do you propose the merging takes place manually? I can save this sibling MOC and it'll go to the persistent store and I can not have it skip the mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:. But then how do I get the main MOC's FRC made aware? If you have some code snippets, that might help clarify. Thanks!

Comment: IdStar, your challenge is that you want all of your background MOCs to merge at the same time. I think you've chosen a complex way to solve your problem. A better way is to use the same background MOC and then perform a single save for all of your data. I suggested the hack because it was one solution. I don't know enough about your code to send you a snippet. Frankly, you are fighting the framework. You will lose that battle. Andrew

Comment: Adonoho - agreed. After struggling with this, I sensed code smell and refactored to not be sequence dependent on managed objects getting automatically merged in. I did want to know if it was possible to suppress notifications picked up by the FRC, but the lesson seems to be, no.

Comment: IdStar, As you appear to have accepted my answer/conversation, would you consider formally accepting the answer so I may gain some karma points? (I.e. check the green check mark next to my answer above.) Thanks, Andrew

Comment: adonoho - I'm always happy to give out Karma points. In this case however, I don't want the Q&A to be misleading to others who come here, thinking there's an answer to the original question. We've both just careened off into agreeing that the original premise isn't ideal. But technically, how to defer notifications until the merge has completed (as a transaction), has not been answered. I do appreciate you having chimed in though!

Comment: idStar, your assessment is the final word. I, nonetheless, think we did answer the question. The answer is to not try to solve this problem the way you attempted to solve it. That the "right" CD way to solve it is to have all of your updates occur in a single MOC. Then a single `-save:` will provide the single update needed to trigger your controller to update your tables. While we didn't talk about it, this is also the way to create atomic saves via locking the store coordinator. An answer that one should not solve a problem your way is an answer. And it is one that should be seen. Andrew

Comment: adonoho - in my use case (an import operation), it's not a good idea to use one single MOC (the main thread's one in this case), b/c it'll block the main thread and reduce UI responsiveness, hence the original saving/merging from another context.